# no such property: it for class

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to retrieve a list of all instances of 'search' from a json response and set it so that any values that contains 'null' is changed to 0. However I am getting an error stating `no such property: it for class.` How can I fix this to ensure I get the code working so any instance of 'null' changes to 0?

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
    def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
    def json =  new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)


    def resultItems = json.xxx.xxx.items
    def resultSearchCostGroup = json.xxx.xxx.xxx.search
    int totalSearchCostGroup = resultSearchCostGroup.flatten().collect(it ?:0 ).sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line should read

```
int totalSearchCostGroup = resultSearchCostGroup.flatten().collect { it ?:0 }.sum()
```

Comment: oh man really, wow soap is harsh on write spaces. Just one other question for me to put a test. Can you tell me how to code a list so that in the list it contains values [200, null, 150, 34, null, 20, 0, 5] please and set it as the variable resultSearchCostGroup? I want to put the line of code in your answer to practice to ensure the sum works correctly. At the moment resultSearchCostGroup is all null in the list so the sum is correct that it shows 0, I just want to test with a mixture of values to ensure the sum works as I hope it does

Comment: This was not about spaces, but about curly braces vs. round braces. Your code was simple non-valid Groovy. As for the list, you already got the correct syntax: `def resultSearchCostGroup = [200, null, 150, 34, null, 20, 0, 5]`